# Using FloatingActionButton and adding library design prevents build

Tags: android

while trying to add a FloatingActionButton to my layout, I have been told by AndroidStudio, that I need to add the library design for that:

"This operation requires the library design.
Would you like to add this library now?"

I clicked "Ok", and now the build completely fails.

So far I have managed to find a line in the file "build.gradle", which I hoped was responsible for the issue:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
```

I tried to comment it out and rebuild, but the error remains.

The errors given are:

```
C:\AndroidProjects\ChartExample\app\src\main\res\layout\child_edit.xml
Error:(20, 39) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_alignBaseline' with value '@id/etFirstName').
Error:(38, 39) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_alignBaseline' with value '@id/etLastName').
Error:(54, 39) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_alignBaseline' with value '@id/etBirthday').
Error:(73, 39) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_alignBaseline' with value '@id/rbFemale').
C:\AndroidProjects\ChartExample\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\layout\child_edit.xml
Error:(20, 39) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_alignBaseline' with value '@id/etFirstName').
Error:(38, 39) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_alignBaseline' with value '@id/etLastName').
Error:(54, 39) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_alignBaseline' with value '@id/etBirthday').
Error:(73, 39) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_alignBaseline' with value '@id/rbFemale').
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

I guess these errors are mainly because the build didn't finish and some resource files haven't been generated, but I'm not sure.

Does someone have an idea how to undo what I have done to my project by hitting this fatal button?
Thanks for any help you can give.

Carsten

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project ?

Comment: Thanks Christophe, I just tried. The error remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was that all of the UI elements mentioned in the error messages had a cycle reference in the layout xml. The error had nothing to do with the libraries added.